# how to detect when ad is shown iAdBanner

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

How do I detect when the user clicks on the ad banner and an ad is shown? Currently I'm using the following code to show and hide the banner depending on if an ad is available, but I'm not sure how to detect if the ad banner is opened.

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    // Show the ad banner.
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.adBanner.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Show the ad banner.
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.adBanner.alpha = 0.0;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Did you try the delegate bannerViewActionShouldBegin?

Answer (score 0):

Implement related iAD delegate method

Parameters

banner: The banner view that the user tapped.

willLeave: YES if another application will be launched to execute the action; NO if the action is going to be executed inside your application

SWIFT

```
optional func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(_ banner: ADBannerView!,
                 willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool
```

OBJECTIVE-C

```
 - (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner
           willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
```